# Secondary namenode connection timed out

Tags: hadoop, ssh

I'm trying to set up hadoop on my Mac Mojave 10.14.6. The hadoop version I'm using is 3.0.3

I followed this tutorial to set up the config: https://dbmstutorials.com/hive/hdfs-setup-on-mac.html

While running hdfs namenode -format I have this following error for the secondary namenode:

```
Starting secondary namenodes [xp]
xp: ssh: connect to host xp port 22: Operation timed out
2019-12-09 09:26:03,796 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
```

I allowed remote login and created ssh keys without password and desactivate the fire wall to check if it could help but the problem remains. Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Did you try to execute ssh <your MacBook IP> from MacBook itself? Did it work ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes I tried to ssh xp and it didn't work. After investigating a bit more I managed to make it work...

I changed the ip in the /etc/hosts from 127.0.1.1 to another one which were responding to the ping. I don't know why the ip 127.0.1.1 didn't work but at least the problem seems to be fixed for now